# how to do on select option exclude values or include values

Tags: jquery, html

how to change values dynamically, when i enter or erase the "ship" values and how to do include tax 13% and exclude tax on select option with grand total. here is my code: [Jsfifddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aouznja/5/)

```
<script>
(function() {
 "use strict";

$("table").on("change", "input", function() {
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
var qty = parseFloat(row.find(".quantity").val());
var price = parseFloat(row.find(".productprice").val());
var tcost = qty * price;
row.find(".tcost").val(isNaN(tcost) ? "" : tcost);

 var totalValue = 0;
 $(document).find(".tcost").each(function(){
totalValue += parseFloat($(this).val());
 });
 var tax = totalValue * 13/100;
 $("#tax").val(tax);

 totalValue = totalValue + tax;

 var ship = $('#ship').val();
 totalValue = parseFloat(totalValue) + parseFloat(ship);


 $("#total").val(totalValue);
});

})();   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to offend, but your code needs help. First, let me walk you through some fixes to your HTML.

`<tr for="input01">` is wrong. `<tr>` doesn't have a `for` attribute. You also need to space out your attributes for valid HTML.

Your line `<input type='text' class="tax" id="tax" name="tax" placeholder="Tax amount" class="price" disabled/>` has two class attributes.

Now, for the fixes. Basically the reason why your code was failing was two-fold:

- **Number vs. ParseFloat**: The `Number` datatype conversion function in javascript is handled slightly differently than `parseFloat`, specifically when it comes to empty strings. `Number` will turn `''` into `0` whereas `parseFloat` will turn it into `NaN`.
- **Scope**: Your `row.find(class)` method didn't extend to the tax and shipping fields because those were not part of the table. Moreover, your event handler was only for `<table>`, but the shipping and tax calculators were out of `table`, in `body` or even `document`. As a result, when you tried to access the `.val()` method on `row.find('.shipping')`, you got `NaN`.

  Further on this point, your second argument for the event handler was `input`, with no provision for `select`'s change event.

[I've fixed your code with a jsFiddle where I address these issues and fix your HTML as well](http://jsfiddle.net/2aouznja/17/). In case the link becomes inaccessible, I've included the code below.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered inventory" style="width:95%;float:right;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" />
            </th>
            <th>S. No</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price per Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' class='case' />
            </td>
            <td><span id='snum'>1.</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='productname_1' name='productname[]' required />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' id='itemcode_1' name='itemcode[]' required />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="number quantity" id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]' style="width:165px;" required />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="number productprice" id='productprice_1' name='productprice[]' style="width:165px;" required />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class="number tcost" id='tcost_1' name='tcost[]' style="width:165px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="" style="width:280px; float:right;">
    <br>
    <label>Tax Type
        <select class="number" style="margin-left: 8px;" id="taxoptions" required>
            <option value="">Select Tax Type</option>
            <option value="excludetax">Exclude Tax</option>
            <option value="Includetax">Include Tax</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label style="margin-left: 33px;">13%
        <input type='text' class="tax" id="tax" name="tax" placeholder="Tax amount" disabled />
        <br>
        <br>
    </label>
    <input type='text' id='ship' name='ship' placeholder="shipping amount" class="ship" style="margin-left: 51px;" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type='text' id='total' name='total' placeholder="Total amount" class="total" style="margin-left: 60px;" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox inline" style="margin-left: 60px;">
        <input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox" value="sendemail">Send E-mail</label>
    <br>
    <br>    <span>
                                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class='btn btn-success' style="width:100px; margin-left: 54px;" />
                                                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-success' style="width:100px; margin-left: 22px;">Print</button>
                                                </span>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 (function () {

     $(document).on("change", "input, select", function (e) {
         var row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var qty = Number(row.find(".quantity").val());
         var price = Number(row.find(".productprice").val());
         var ship = Number($("#ship").val());
         var tcost = 0;
         tcost = qty * price;
         var totalValue = 0;
         var taxAmount = 0;

         row.find(".tcost").val(isNaN(tcost) ? "" : tcost);
         totalValue += Number($("#tcost_1").val());
         console.log(row.find(".tcost").val());

         if ($('#taxoptions').val() != 'Includetax') {
             taxAmount = 0;
             $('#tax').val(taxAmount);
         } else {
             taxAmount = totalValue * .13;
             $('#tax').val(taxAmount);
         }


         totalValue += Number(taxAmount + ship);

         $('#total').val(totalValue);

     });

 })();
```

Comment: thank u and i learned from here jquery option values include & exclude